# show $A^TAx=A^Tb$ has a solution with Rank (A) not necessarily n

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, transpose

There is a sytem $Ax=b$ **with rank A not necessarily n**
How to prove that
$A^TAx=A^Tb$
Has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $x$ is a solution exactly when $Ax-b\in \ker A^T$.